# Crystal Report in ASP.Net passing parameter values and no valid report source

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I having trouble displaying a Crystal report on a ASP.Net web page. The website is an internal website only so you'll see that I have file path coded into the site. I think I'm very close the getting this to work, but I'm obviously missing something. Can anyone help?

He is my code:

```
void BindReport()
{
    ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();

    //Report is saved on an external server which I have full access too
    rd.Load(@"\\MyServer\Reports\MyReport.rpt");
    rd.SetDatabaseLogon("UserName", "Password", "MyServer", "MyDatabase", true);
    //The Report has 2 parameter and links directly to a stored procedure on a SQL Server
    rd.SetParameterValue("@uspDateFrom", new DateTime(2012, 05, 01));
    rd.SetParameterValue("@uspDateTo", new DateTime(2012, 05, 31));
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh = true;
    CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}

//I call my report on a button click
protected void buttonPreviewReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindReport();
}
```

When the report tries to run I get a dialog box pop up asking for my parameter values even though I've already passed them in!? and even if I enter them on the dialog prompt I then receive a message saying that no valid report source is available.

Anybody got any ideas?

I'm using ASP.Net 4.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem I was getting once when I was working with Crystal Report.

```
  ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();

  ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();

  ParameterDiscreteValue discreteVal = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

  paramField.ParameterFieldName = "@examid";// This is how you can send Parameter Value to the Crystal Report


 // Set the first discrete value and pass it to the parameter.
   discreteVal.Value = ddlAllExam.SelectedValue;//Value from DropDown

   paramField.CurrentValues.Add(discreteVal);

   paramFields.Add(paramField);

   CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;

   string datasource = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Data Source"].ToString();

   string Database = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"].ToString();

   string Userid = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Userid"].ToString();

   string Password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString();

    ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();

    report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/AllExamReport.rpt"));//Here you can give the Path of external Server

    report.SetDatabaseLogon(Userid, Password, datasource, Database);

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
```

Hope this will help you.!!!